# How to use custom label inside Soql query for Date Value

Tags: apex, soql, customlabel

I am using Custom label inside soql query for Date values. But I am getting error.

```
String startvalue=System.Label.Start_CloseDate;
        String endvalue=System.Label.End_CloseDate;


        List<Opportunity> Opp = new List<Opportunity>();      
        Opp = [select Id  from Opportunity 
        where StageName NOT in('Duplicate','Closed Lost','Cancelled','Prospect','Active - Low Probability','Active - Med. Probability') 
        AND CloseDate >= startvalue AND CloseDate <= endvalue  ];
```

(0r)

```
List<Opportunity> Opp = new List<Opportunity>();      
            Opp = [select Id  from Opportunity 
            where StageName NOT in('Duplicate','Closed Lost','Cancelled','Prospect','Active - Low Probability','Active - Med. Probability') 
            AND CloseDate >= System.Label.Start_CloseDate AND CloseDate <= System.Label.Start_CloseDate  ];
```

Comment: This looks like more of a setting than label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data type has to match if you want to use binding on an inline query. You also need the ":" characters in order to cause a binding.

```
    Date startvalue = Date.valueOf(System.Label.Start_CloseDate);
    Date endvalue = Date.valueOf(System.Label.End_CloseDate);
    List<Opportunity> Opp = [select Id  from Opportunity 
    where StageName NOT in('Duplicate','Closed Lost','Cancelled','Prospect','Active - Low Probability','Active - Med. Probability') 
    AND CloseDate >= :startvalue AND CloseDate <= :endvalue  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need dynamic SOQL to make it work. If you do something like the following:

```
String soql = 'SELECT ... FROM Opportunity WHERE ... ' +
    ' AND CloseDate >= ' + Label.MyCloseDateStart +
    ' AND CloseDate <= ' + Label.MyCloseDateEnd;
```

Then you can use label values with a specific date (e.g. `2017-10-11`), or any date literal you please (e.g. `THIS_MONTH`). Note that when using untrusted input in a dynamic query, it is best practice to escape it.

```
String.escapeSingleQuotes(Label.MyCloseDateStart);
```